# Rails - bin/rails generate doesn't work in recreated project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just red "Getting Started with Rails" and trying to create a blog project again from scratch.

I've created a new environment for rails projects with vagrant/virtualbox/ubuntu 12.04

Here is the problem.
I've create a new rails project with

```
rails new blog
```

Thereafter, using

```
bin/rails generate controller pages
```

I've create a controller, and continued working with project. After some time, I've decided to delete the blog project and start again from scratch.

I've started a new iteration

```
rails new blog | works fine
cd blog
bin/rails generate controller pages | does not create a controller, does not terminate, only with control + C
```

I've repeated all steps with a new project blog2. And the result was the same. If i create a new project, then delete it, then create a project with the same name

```
bin/rails generate
```

will not work.

Rubu 2.1.3/Rails 4.1.6
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you removed tables from database which created during blog?

Comment: I did not create any models, and did not manipulate any data. Should I still care about it ?

Comment: did you ran `rake db:create` at the first time blog project creating? If yes then second time when you use the same name..Even you delete folder but in database that table should be there so better to remove that table then try to run again with the same name

Comment: No I did not. Just bin/rails generate controller

Comment: which error u r getting?

Comment: There are no errors. I put the command bin/rails generate controller ... and the terminal does not response. Only if I press Ctrl+C it terminate. That is all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by executing:

**spring stop**

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using RVM. I had to close that terminal, opened another terminal, then switched back to that version of ruby.

After that everything worked fine again.